# Sqlitedatabase query not working when selecting by _id

Tags: android, sqlite

I've been stuck on this problem with my sqlitedatabase for several days now.

My insert method works, I break after it has been run and check that the database now contain rows (before it was empty), by querying for the entire database, which works.
This is the insert method which returns the generated puzzleId.

```
    public int savePuzzleToEdit(ContentValues puzzle, Integer puzzleId) {
      Integer id = puzzle.getAsInteger(General.ID);
      if (id == 0 && puzzleId == null) {
        puzzle.remove(General.ID);
        puzzleId = (int) ourDatabase.insert(PUZZLE_TABLE, null, puzzle);
      }else {
        ....
      }
    return puzzleId
```

The query method however, does not return any results, aka the cursor is empty.

```
public ArrayList<ContentValues> getCreatedPuzzles(int puzzleId) {
  Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(PUZZLE_TABLE, null, "_id = " + puzzleId, null, null, null, null, null);
        while (c.moveToNext()) { // Generate return list ...}
```

I have tried breaking after the insert and before the query in order to see if there is indeed rows in the database, which there is. I am however not able to query by selecting by id. I can however, query by the other fields in the table and get the correct rows as a result, so it has to be the _id field which has an error.

I have also tried to use the rawQuery method which also works when querying for the entire database or by any of the other fields but id.

This is the create statement:

```
private static final String PUZZLE_TABLE_CREATE =
            "CREATE TABLE puzzle ( _id INTEGER, name varchar(45), category " +
                    "varchar(25), publishdate DATE, rating INT, timesplayed INT, numberOfQuestions INT);";
```

As I understood it the id has to be INTEGER in order to auto_increment on insert, which I believe works since the insert method returns a id, which varies from one insert to another.

The query method does not return any errors or exceptions, and it just seems like there are no rows in the table with that id. I have assumed that the returned puzzleId is also being stored as the id in the table, but that might be wrong?!

Any and I mean any suggestions or insights on how to try to fix this problem is highly appreciated.

Comment: How do you insert puzzles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first thing first your create table statement might be wrong the _id will not autoincrement if you don't mention it in the statement. it should be like this

_id integer primary key autoincrement

and also check your create table statement for other errors

Comment: In order for autoincrement to work primary key had to be specified, which fixed my problem =)